# How to avoid CRT dialog with assert(..) function

Tags: c++, c, windows

Is there a way in Windows to avoid CRT dialog on failure with assert(..) function? I like to get the error message printed to the console. Can CrtReportMode(..) be used if we don't define NDEBUG in optimized version to achieve this?

-Kartlee

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`_CrtSetReportMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportmode?view=vs-2019) and [`_CrtSetReportFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetreportfile?view=vs-2019) to send the output to a file (in this case `stderr`) instead.

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE)
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR );
```

Regarding the use in a release build, note the remarks and libraries sections:

> When _DEBUG is not defined, calls to _CrtSetReportMode are removed during preprocessing.
>
> Libraries: Debug versions of C Run-Time Libraries only.